# What is the alternative to match different constructor parameter names in Automapper besides ForCtorParam

Tags: c#, type-conversion, automapper

There are 3 classes I use in a conversion using Automapper 8.1.0

```
public class A{
   public int Length{ get; set; }
   public int FrequencyHz{ get; set; }
   public int RXWaveguide { get; set; }
}

public class C{
   public C(double time) {
        Time = time;            
    }
   public double Time { get; }
}

public class B : C {
   public int Length{ get; }
   public int TXWaveguide { get; }
   public B(double time, int length, int txWaveguide) : base(time) {
        Length = length;
        TXWaveguide = txWaveguide;
    }
}
```

I want to convert from `A` to `B`, where `B` is inherited from `C`.

The code below shows my `Automapper configuration`.

```
var objA = new A() {
                 Length = 5,
                 FrequencyHz = 5,
                 RXWaveguide = 5
             };

 var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
               .ForCtorParam("time", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (double)1 / src.FrequencyHz))
               .ForCtorParam("txWaveguide", opt => opt.MapFrom(srcA => srcA.RXWaveguide * 10));
        });
        var myMapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
        mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        return myMapper.Map<B>(input);
```

I am not comfortable using string name in `ForCtorParam`.

Is there other alternative way of mapping class A to B using `Automapper`, but not with `ForCtorParam`?

Thank you

Comment: You can use `ConstructUsing` instead.

Comment: I think is not neccesary use the configuration. Add an empty constructor in your B class and then create the map without any specific config.